# How to enable Firebase Realtime Database in GCP?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform

**I want to extend an existing GCP project with a Firebase Realtime Database.**

According to the Firebase documentation,

- all Firebase projects are internally hosted on GCP
- it is possible to use Firebase features directly from a GCP project,

so I went to the Marketplace and found the corresponding product page there.

Unlike other product pages, this one doesn't have an "Enable" button on it but rather "Get started for free".

**This button does nothing, no response at all. Any deas?**

[image: GCP Marketplace]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just go to the Firebase console and from there you will be able to use Firebase Realtime Database for the same project.

It is not possible to use all the features of Firebase directly on Google Cloud Platform, but you will find common products as Storage and Cloud Functions i.e. that are shared between Firebase and Cloud Platform

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, @Chris32. I had been hoping that it would be possible to work with only one of the consoles; sad to hear that this is currently not the case. I am facing another problem there; when I open the start page of the Firebase console, I see suggestions to import some of my other GCP projects but not this one. Do I need to configure something else, or could it be that (in Firebase) this project name is already taken and the import hence not possible???

Comment: *firebaser here* Any GCP project that you're an owner on that doesn't have Firebase associated with it yet, should show up in the "import project" drop-down on the Firebase console. If a project doesn't, [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting.